# Modify a row in the table and save the change in the database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I would like to modify a column through a href link, I could change but this change will not be saved in the database that can help me?
in my controller:

```
public function updateAlertesAction()
{  
   $date=$this->getRequest()->query->get('date');
   $CI=$this->getRequest()->query->get('CI');
   $cell=$this->getRequest()->query->get('cell');

   $kpi_name=$this->getRequest()->query->get('cmts');

   $KPI = $this->getDoctrine()
               ->getEntityManager()
               ->getRepository('AdminBlogBundle:StatAlert')
                ->findBy(array('cell' => '$idKPI', 'ci' => '$CI', 'dat' => '$date'));

         $KPI->setCmts($kpi_name);
         $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
         $em->persist($KPI);
         $em->flush();

     return new Response ($kpi_name.' Updaate Ok : '.$KPI->getCmts());
}
```

He displays this error msg

> **Fatal error**:  Call to a member function format() on a non-object in **D:\EasyPHP-5.3.3.1\www\alerteurs1\vendor\doctrine-dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateType.php** on line **44**

if I replace the search ->find(array('cell' => 'TUN1196S1'));
I have  Warning: array_combine() [function.array-combine]: Both parameters should have an equal number of elements in D:\EasyPHP-5.3.3.1\www\alerteurs1\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository.php line 126

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your $date should be a `\Datetime` Object?

Comment: /**
     * @var date $dat
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="DAT", type="date", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $dat;

Comment: Yes, that means it should be a `\DateTime`.

Comment: @aderuwe Can you tell me more

Comment: `$date = new \DateTime($this->getRequest()->query->get('date'));` but that works only if your date is in a workable format. Check http://be2.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php for more information.

Comment: thank you , but i have a problem please help me :( DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: Failed to parse time string (30/10/2012) at position 0 (3): Unexpected character

Comment: Could you give us the current value / format of you var `$date`?

Comment: $dat = new \DateTime($this->getRequest()->query->get('dat'));

Comment: And if you do a `die(var_dump($dat))` what it returns you?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the single quotes around your variables in the array declaration:

```
->findBy(array('cell' => '$idKPI', 'ci' => '$CI', 'dat' => '$date'));
```

Should rather look like:

```
->findBy(array('cell' => $idKPI, 'ci' => $CI, 'dat' => $date));
```

Comment: the same error with ->findBy(array('cell' => $idKPI, 'ci' => $CI, 'dat' => $date));

Comment: if I replace the search ->find(array('cell' => 'TUN1196S1'));
I have  Warning: array_combine() [<a href='function.array-combine'>function.array-combine</a>]: Both parameters should have an equal number of elements in D:\EasyPHP-5.3.3.1\www\alerteurs1\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository.php line 126

Comment: Ah, yes, I was mistaken. I think CoBaLt2760's answer is correct.